# Group by after left and inner joins

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have to group by based on field DT and count its number of occurences. Tables are stored in Google Big Query.

```
SELECT c.Id1 AS HId, d.Id1 as PId,e.Type as DT
FROM
[RawGps32.T20160601] c
LEFT JOIN
[VN_20160601] d
ON c.Id1 = d.Id1
INNER JOIN [SF.DT] e
ON d.Id1 = e.Id1
GROUP BY HId, PId,DT
HAVING HId in (3928,3602,1285,4663,96546)
```

Current Result:

```
HId     PId     DT
3928    11      G1
3602    12      G3
1285    12      G1
4663    14      G4
96546   15      G1
```

Expected Result

```
 DT  count
 G1  3
 G3  1
 G4  1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably

```
SELECT e.Type as DT, count(*) as count
FROM
[RawGps32.T20160601] c
LEFT JOIN
[VN_20160601] d
ON c.Id1 = d.Id1
INNER JOIN [SF.DT] e
ON d.Id1 = e.Id1
WHERE c.Id1 in (3928,3602,1285,4663,96546)
GROUP BY e.Type
ORDER BY e.Type
```

Note also your `LEFT JOIN [VN_20160601] d` is effectively `INNER` due to following `INNER JOIN [SF.DT] e ON d.Id1 = e.Id1` which prohibits NULLs at `d.id1`. Probably both should be `LEFT JOIN`.